# How to check if client is still connected with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, multithreading, ffmpeg, client-server, live-streaming

I am working on a live-streaming server in C++ using FFMPEG. 
I have a I have an acquisition thread which grabs the images from the cameras and I spawn a new thread on each client connexion to send them the packets.

Here's my "send" function:

```
void Encoder::_encode()
{
    int ret = 0;
    if (avcodec_send_frame(ctx, frame) < 0)
        throw new std::runtime_error("error sending a frame for encoding");
    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        avio_write(client, pkt->data, pkt->size);
        avio_flush(client);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}
```

This encodes the frame and sends it to the client.

The problem is: whenever the client exits, the thread keeps sending it data, and throws no exception, even when the same client connects again, it will spawn a new thread while the old one keeps running...
Is there a way to "ping" the client to check whether it is still connected?

Comment: What is this "client"? I guess you can always set a condition variable to synchronize this "send" function thread and the client thread.

Comment: @halfelf the "client" is (currently) vlc but the idea is to make a RTP server so any http request

Comment: `AVIOContext` struct contains `error` field that you can check. However it is not a good idea to utilize avio for io. You should definitely use something else (and probably async).

Comment: @VTT any suggestions?